# How to find the lowest upper bound of a set

Tags: real-analysis

Given a set (see picture, an explanation of either set would be helpful) how would I find the lowest upper bound and prove that it is indeed the lowest upper bound? And if it does not have a lowest upper bound how do I prove that? Btw use of limits is not allowed.[image]

Comment: There is no procedure/algorithm for such problems like there is to find GCD of two numbers. Just think a little about the numbers in given set and guess few upper bounds. Unless the problem is difficult you will be able to guess the lowest upper bound and then prove it.

Answer (score 0):

For the set (i), please note that $3$ is an upper bound for this set. Also as there is a sequence of rationals smaller than $1$ that converge to $1$, the $3$ should be also the lowest upper bound.

Comment: How did you determine the upper bound was 3?

Comment: From the inequality given in your set. That is $1/x>1$ or $-1/x<-1$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

for (i) for $n∈\mathbb{N}$,

$(\frac{1}{n})→0$

for (ii) for $n∈\mathbb{N}$

$(\frac{n}{n+2})→1$

Answer (score 0):

For (i), we see that $3$ is the lowest upper bound of this set. This is clear because $x$ can get arbitrarily close to $1$, so $-\frac{1}{x}$ can get arbitrarily close to $-1$. Also, not that all the values of $x$ not 'close to $1$' give the fraction a larger negative value. i.e. as $x$ increases, $4-\frac{1}{x}$decreases.
This intuitively uses limits, so I will show this in a more rigorous way.

For $x \in \Bbb Q, \ x \in (0,1)$ we show that: $4-\frac{1}{x} < 3$.

$0 < x < 1 \implies 1 < \frac{1}{x} \implies 4 < 3 + \frac{1}{x} \implies 4 -\frac{1}{x} < 3$

So, $3$ must be an upper bound. To show that it is the least upper bound, we show that any number smaller than $3$ is not an upper bound. i.e. for any $\epsilon > 0, \ 3 - \epsilon < 4 - \frac{1}{x}$ for a small enough $x$.

$3 - \epsilon < 4 - \frac{1}{x} \implies \frac{1}{x} < 1 + \epsilon$. From here it is evident that for any $\epsilon > 0$, we can find some $x$ value that makes this true (this comes from the archimedean property). Thus, $3 - \epsilon$ is not an upper bound. Thus, $3$ is the lowest upper bound.

For (iii), we can show that $\frac{n}{n+2} < \frac{n+1}{(n+1)+2}$.

$\frac{n}{n+2} < \frac{n+1}{n+3} \implies n(n+3) < (n+1)(n+2) \implies n^2 +3n < n^2 +3n +2$, which is obviously true. So, each element of the set will be larger than the last, thus this set has no upper bound *in* the set.

This set does have a lowest upper bound, namely $1$, we prove this by showing that $1 > \frac{n}{n+2}$ for all $n > 0$. Then show that $1-\epsilon <  \frac{n}{n+2}$ for any $\epsilon > 0$ and a large enough $n$.

For any $n > 0$, it is clear that $n + 2 > n$. Thus, $1 > \frac{n}{n+2}$. We prove the second part. $1-\epsilon (n+2) <  n \implies n+2 - n \epsilon -2 \epsilon <  n \implies 2 < n \epsilon +2 \epsilon$, this can be satisfied with a sufficiently large $n$ (by the archimedean property). Thus, $1$ is the least lower bound of that set